# OpenIddict: options.DisableScopeValidation() not disabling scope validation

Tags: openiddict

Really sorry if this is a stupid question, but somehow I can't get options.DisableScopeValidation() working.

My code

```
// OpenIddict
builder.Services.AddOpenIddict()
    .AddCore(options =>
    {
        options.UseEntityFrameworkCore().UseDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
    })
    .AddServer(options =>
    {
        // Flow
        options
        .AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow().RequireProofKeyForCodeExchange()
        .AllowClientCredentialsFlow()
        .AllowRefreshTokenFlow();

        options.SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("/connect/authorize"); // Ni flow yang user login kt VentureAuth.
        options.SetTokenEndpointUris("/connect/token"); // Token Endpoint: Clients nak mintak token, mintak kat sini.
        options.SetUserinfoEndpointUris("/connect/userinfo");

        // Can disable access token encryption if want to read access token
        // https://dev.to/robinvanderknaap/setting-up-an-authorization-server-with-openiddict-part-iii-client-credentials-flow-55lp
        options
            .AddEphemeralEncryptionKey()
            .AddEphemeralSigningKey()
            .DisableAccessTokenEncryption();

        //options.RegisterScopes("api");

        options
            .UseAspNetCore()
            .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough()
            .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough()
            .EnableUserinfoEndpointPassthrough();

        options.DisableScopeValidation();

    });
```

I can retrieve a token when I don't send any scope. However, whenever I send any other undefined scopes, I get the message:

```
error:invalid_request
error_description:This client application is not allowed to use the specified scope.
error_uri:https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2051
```

This is a screenshot of the request I've made:
[Screenshot of POSTMAN request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNSa7.png)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, only after I posted the question on StackOverflow is when I manage to get the answer myself.

For this case, the error message is referring to the Scope PERMISSION of the client application.

So, to disable Scope Permission checking, add the following line;

```
options.IgnoreScopePermissions();
```

Thank you and hope this helps other people as well.